# parsing nested JSON in javascript - what is the invalid character

Tags: javascript, json

I am using JSOn in my javascript code. the javascript gets the following JSON message:

```
{"param1":1, "param2":{"aaa":1,"bbb":2,"ccc":3}, "param3":true}
```

In JavaScript I wrote the following code:

```
parsedArgs = JSON.parse(args);
alert(parsedArgs.param2);
parsedArgs.param2= JSON.parse(parsedArgs.param2);
```

in the alert I can see [Object object]
but JSON.parse(parsedArgs.param2) fails with SyntaxError: invalidcharacter.

I want to get the inner parameters of param2 but JSON parser is not working.
can you please help me? what is my problem?

thanks

Comment: aren't you missing quotes around param2?

Comment: `JSON.parse()` expects a JSON string, not an arbitrary JavaScript variable. See LightStyle's answer.

Comment: If the alert displays [Object object] then parsedArgs.param2 is already a parsed object. You dont ned to parse it again. Try alerting  `alert(parsedArgs.param2.aaa);` and check the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are parsing your JSON string too much time. `JSON.parse` is a recursive function which converts a string to a valid JS object using the JSON format. This means that once you have parsed it with the first `JSON.parse` you don't have to parse again object's properties, because they have already been parsed. You can access it directly doing `parsedArgs.param2.aaa` for example.

Answer (score 0):

missing quotes in param2

```
{
    "param1": 1,
    "param2": {
        "aaa": 1,
        "bbb": 2,
        "ccc": 3
    },
    "param3": true
}
```